# Updating a field in a list with a number from a different list

Tags: list, workflow, calculated-column

I'm working on SharePoint 2010. I have two lists, Devices and Knownissues. In Devices I have the ID column with an item generated number which I want to update in a column in Knownissues called DevicesID.

I already have a Lookup field in Knownissues. I tried updating the field using Nintex Workflow but have been banging my head against a brick wall (the best result I can get is returning '1' and not the actual number in the ID column). Surely there's a straight forward way of doing this? I was thinking a calculated field, but I am happy to hear suggestions.

Comment: No, Calculated Columns can't do this.. So do NOT bang your head against that wall again .. it is giving you the wrong answers

Comment: The Workflow is giving me the wrong answer. I was wondering if there was another way to achieve what I need to do?

Comment: I would like to help, but I am very confused about what you are trying to achieve. Are you saying that you have several items in the Knownissues list and you need to update the lookup field named DevicesID for each of these items in the Knowissues list? If yes, then what criteria would you use to identify which ID from the Devices list corresponds to an item in the Knowissues list?

Comment: I just need to update the 'DeviceID' column in the Knownissues list with the 'ID' column number in the Devices list.

Comment: It is not clear what you need, could you clarify?

Comment: I have a SharePoint List called Devices which has a column in it called ID. When an item is added an incremental number is added to to the ID column. 

I have another SharePoint list called KnownIssues, in this list I have a column called DeviceID. I need to get update the DeviceID column with the number from the ID column from the Devices list. Does that make sense?

Comment: Why dont you add additional lookup column into list. This will simply add another lookup column to you list, which is not available in New/Edit form but will be available for List View and will be available in all of the Object Model i.e. Server/Client/REST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a event handler for the Devices list that will update the Id column and DeviceId column when a item is added to the list. Event handlers are more complex than workflows but here is the basic info on [Event Handlers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff407274(v=office.14).aspx). They offer more flexibility than workflows and allow you to easily access info from other lists.

Answer (score 0):

Create a lookup column *IssueID* in **Devices** list.
Then in the desginer workflow start a workflow when an `item created` in **Devices** list, do the following

First set workflow variable *`issueId`* with integer type & assign *IssueID* (lookup column) integer value in the currentlist(**Devices**).

[image]
Now use `update list item` action,
Select **Knownissues** list & assign *DevicesID* field with currentItem ID(**Devices** list item ID).
Find List Item by matching *ID* field with workflow variable *`issueId`*.
[image]

For Reference [link](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28111331/Update-a-list-item-from-another-list-by-SP-2010-Designer-workflow.html#answer39119922-20)

Answer (score 0):

Using a SharePoint designer workflow should be able to do this just fine. I'm  not familiar with "Nintex Workflow" but out of the box SharePoint can do this.
Base on your description and names of fields, follow these steps:

1. Create a workflow on for the list "Devices".
2. In the workflow settings screen set the "Start Option" to "Start workflow automatically when an item is created".
3. Add the action "Update List Item" to your workflow.
4. Edit the action and choose the list "Knownissues".
5. Click "Add" and choose "DevicesID" under "Set this field:"
6. Choose "ID" under "To this value:"
7. Save and Publish your workflow.
8. ...
9. Profit?

Comment: If you explain more about the lookup field. I can better explain how step 3 works.